# Adicionar linhas em uma JTable de acordo com ordem crescente

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Estou fazendo um sistema RBC para verificar a similaridade entre computadores. Gostaria de ordenar minhas linhas da tabela pelo valor da probabilidade. O problema é que a tabela tem em torno de 9.500.000 linhas. Alguém sabe como ordenar linhas por coluna?

Segue abaixo o método que estou utilizando no meu código:

```
package mce;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Vector;
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class MCE {

public static double  retornaSimGabinete(String a1, String a2){
        if (a1.equals("Full Tower") && a2.equals("Full Tower"))  {
                return 1;
        } else if (a1.equals("Mid Tower") && a2.equals("Mid Tower")) {
                return 1;
        } else if ((a1.equals("Full Tower") && a2.equals("Mid Tower")) || (a2.equals("Full Tower") && a1.equals("Mid Tower"))) {
                return 0.5;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
}

public static double retornaSimProc (String a1, String a2) {
        if (a1.equals("i7 6700K") && a2.equals("i7 6700K")) {
                return 1;
        } else if (a1.equals("i7 6700") && a2.equals("i7 6700")) {
                return 1;
        } else if (a1.equals("i5 6600K") && a2.equals("i5 6600K")) {
                return 1;
        } else if (a1.equals("i5 6600") && a2.equals("i5 6600")) {
                return 1;
        } else if ((a1.equals("i7 6700K") && a2.equals("i7 6700")) || (a2.equals("i7 6700K") && a1.equals("i7 6700"))) {
                return 0.8;
        } else if ((a1.equals("i7 6700K") && a2.equals("i5 6600K")) || (a2.equals("i7 6700K") && a1.equals("i5 6600K"))) {
                return 0.6;    
        } else if ((a1.equals("i7 6700K") && a2.equals("i5 6600")) || (a2.equals("i7 6700K") && a1.equals("i5 6600"))) {
                return 0.4;
        } else if ((a1.equals("i7 6700") && a2.equals("i5 6600K")) || (a2.equals("i7 6700") && a1.equals("i5 6600K"))) {
                return 0.5;
        } else if ((a1.equals("i7 6700") && a2.equals("i5 6600")) || (a2.equals("i7 6700") && a1.equals("i5 6600"))) {
                return 0.7;
        } else if ((a1.equals("i5 6600K") && a2.equals("i5 6600")) || (a2.equals("i5 6600K") && a1.equals("i5 6600"))) {
                return 0.8;
        } else {
                return 0;
        }
}   

public static double retornaSimMem (String a1, String a2) {
        if (a1.equals("HyperX 8GB 1600") && a2.equals("HyperX 8GB 1600")) {
                return 1;
        } else if (a1.equals("HyperX 8GB 1866") && a2.equals("HyperX 8GB 1866")) {
                return 1;
        } else if (a1.equals("HyperX 8GB 2133") && a2.equals("HyperX 8GB 2133")) {
                return 1;
        } else if (a1.equals("Vengeance 8GB 1600") && a2.equals("Vengeance 8GB 1600")) {
                return 1;
        } else if ((a1.equals("HyperX 8GB 1600") && a2.equals("HyperX 8GB 1866")) || (a2.equals("HyperX 8GB 1600") && a1.equals("HyperX 8GB 1866"))) {
                return 0.8;
        } else if ((a1.equals("HyperX 8GB 1600") && a2.equals("HyperX 8GB 2133")) || (a2.equals("HyperX 8GB 1600") && a1.equals("HyperX 8GB 2133"))) {
                return 0.5;    
        } else if ((a1.equals("HyperX 8GB 1600") && a2.equals("Vengeance 8GB 1600")) || (a2.equals("HyperX 8GB 1600") && a1.equals("Vengeance 8GB 1600"))) {
                return 0.9;
        } else if ((a1.equals("HyperX 8GB 1866") && a2.equals("HyperX 8GB 2133")) || (a2.equals("HyperX 8GB 1866") && a1.equals("HyperX 8GB 2133"))) {
                return 0.7;
        } else if ((a1.equals("HyperX 8GB 1866") && a2.equals("Vengeance 8GB 1600")) || (a2.equals("HyperX 8GB 1866") && a1.equals("Vengeance 8GB 1600"))) {
                return 0.8;
        } else if ((a1.equals("HyperX 8GB 2133") && a2.equals("Vengeance 8GB 1600")) || (a2.equals("HyperX 8GB 2133") && a1.equals("Vengeance 8GB 1600"))) {
                return 0.5;
        } else {
                return 0;
        }
}   

public static double retornaSimHd (String a1, String a2) {
        if (a1.equals("WD 1TB 7200") && a2.equals("WD 1TB 7200")) {
                return 1;
        } else if (a1.equals("Seagate 1TB 7200") && a2.equals("Seagate 1TB 7200")) {
                return 1;
        } else if (a1.equals("Seagate 2TB 7200") && a2.equals("Seagate 2TB 7200")) {
                return 1;
        } else if ((a1.equals("WD 1TB 7200") && a2.equals("Seagate 1TB 7200")) || (a2.equals("WD 1TB 7200") && a1.equals("Seagate 1TB 7200"))) {
                return 0.9;
        } else if ((a1.equals("WD 1TB 7200") && a2.equals("Seagate 2TB 7200")) || (a2.equals("WD 1TB 7200") && a1.equals("Seagate 2TB 7200"))) {
                return 0.7;    
        } else if ((a1.equals("Seagate 1TB 7200") && a2.equals("Seagate 2TB 7200")) || (a2.equals("Seagate 1TB 7200") && a1.equals("Seagate 2TB 7200"))) {
                return 0.7;
        } else {
                return 0;
        }
}

public static double retornaSimTeclado (String a1, String a2) {
        if (a1.equals("Razer BlackWidow") && a2.equals("Razer BlackWidow")) {
                return 1;
        } else if (a1.equals("Razer DeathStalker") && a2.equals("Razer DeathStalker")) {
                return 1;
        } else if (a1.equals("Razer Cynosa") && a2.equals("Razer Cynosa")) {
                return 1;
        } else if ((a1.equals("Razer BlackWidow") && a2.equals("Razer DeathStalker")) || (a2.equals("Razer BlackWidow") && a1.equals("Razer DeathStalker"))) {
                return 0.8;
        } else if ((a1.equals("Razer BlackWidow") && a2.equals("Razer Cynosa")) || (a2.equals("Razer BlackWidow") && a1.equals("Razer Cynosa"))) {
                return 0.6;    
        } else if ((a1.equals("Razer DeathStalker") && a2.equals("Razer Cynosa")) || (a2.equals("Razer DeathStalker") && a1.equals("Razer Cynosa"))) {
                return 0.7;
        } else {
                return 0;
        }
}

public static double  retornaSimRefrigeracao(String a1, String a2){
        if (a1.equals("Água") && a2.equals("Água"))  {
                return 1;
        } else if (a1.equals("Ar") && a2.equals("Ar")) {
                return 1;
        } else if ((a1.equals("Água") && a2.equals("Ar")) || (a2.equals("Água") && a1.equals("Ar"))) {
                return 0.5;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
}

public static double retornaSimSsd (String a1, String a2) {
        if (a1.equals("Kingston 120GB") && a2.equals("Kingston 120GB")) {
                return 1;
        } else if (a1.equals("Sandisk 120GB") && a2.equals("Sandisk 120GB")) {
                return 1;
        } else if (a1.equals("Kingston 240GB") && a2.equals("Kingston 240GB")) {
                return 1;
        } else if (a1.equals("Sandisk 240GB") && a2.equals("Sandisk 240GB")) {
                return 1;
        } else if ((a1.equals("Kingston 120GB") && a2.equals("Sandisk 120GB")) || (a2.equals("Kingston 120GB") && a1.equals("Sandisk 120GB"))) {
                return 0.9;
        } else if ((a1.equals("Kingston 120GB") && a2.equals("Kingston 240GB")) || (a2.equals("Kingston 120GB") && a1.equals("Kingston 240GB"))) {
                return 0.7;    
        } else if ((a1.equals("Kingston 120GB") && a2.equals("Sandisk 240GB")) || (a2.equals("Kingston 120GB") && a1.equals("Sandisk 240GB"))) {
                return 0.6;
        } else if ((a1.equals("Sandisk 120GB") && a2.equals("Kingston 240GB")) || (a2.equals("Sandisk 120GB") && a1.equals("Kingston 240GB"))) {
                return 0.6;
        } else if ((a1.equals("Sandisk 120GB") && a2.equals("Sandisk 240GB")) || (a2.equals("Sandisk 120GB") && a1.equals("Sandisk 240GB"))) {
                return 0.7;
        } else if ((a1.equals("Kingston 240GB") && a2.equals("Sandisk 240GB")) || (a2.equals("Kingston 240GB") && a1.equals("Sandisk 240GB"))) {
                return 0.9;
        } else {
                return 0;
        }
}   

public static double retornaSimGpu(String a1, String a2) {
        if (a1.equals("AMD R9 390") && a2.equals("AMD R9 390")) {
                return 1;
        } else if (a1.equals("AMD R9 Fury") && a2.equals("AMD R9 Fury")) {
                return 1;
        } else if (a1.equals("AMD R9 390X") && a2.equals("AMD R9 390X")) {
                return 1;
        } else if (a1.equals("GTX 980 TI") && a2.equals("GTX 980 TI")) {
                return 1;
        } else if ((a1.equals("AMD R9 390") && a2.equals("AMD R9 Fury")) || (a2.equals("AMD R9 390") && a1.equals("AMD R9 Fury"))) {
                return 0.8;
        } else if ((a1.equals("AMD R9 390") && a2.equals("AMD R9 390X")) || (a2.equals("AMD R9 390") && a1.equals("AMD R9 390X"))) {
                return 0.7;    
        } else if ((a1.equals("AMD R9 390") && a2.equals("GTX 980 TI")) || (a2.equals("AMD R9 390") && a1.equals("GTX 980 TI"))) {
                return 0.6;
        } else if ((a1.equals("AMD R9 Fury") && a2.equals("AMD R9 390X")) || (a2.equals("AMD R9 Fury") && a1.equals("AMD R9 390X"))) {
                return 0.7;
        } else if ((a1.equals("AMD R9 Fury") && a2.equals("GTX 980 TI")) || (a2.equals("AMD R9 Fury") && a1.equals("GTX 980 TI"))) {
                return 0.6;
        } else if ((a1.equals("AMD R9 390X") && a2.equals("GTX 980 TI")) || (a2.equals("AMD R9 390X") && a1.equals("GTX 980 TI"))) {
                return 0.8;
        } else {
                return 0;
        }
} 

public static double retornaSimMouse (String a1, String a2) {
        if (a1.equals("Razer Naga") && a2.equals("Razer Naga")) {
                return 1;
        } else if (a1.equals("Razer Abyssus") && a2.equals("Razer Abyssus")) {
                return 1;
        } else if (a1.equals("Razer Krait") && a2.equals("Razer Krait")) {
                return 1;
        } else if (a1.equals("Razer Deathadder") && a2.equals("Razer Deathadder")) {
                return 1;
        } else if ((a1.equals("Razer Naga") && a2.equals("Razer Abyssus")) || (a2.equals("Razer Naga") && a1.equals("Razer Abyssus"))) {
                return 0.7;
        } else if ((a1.equals("Razer Naga") && a2.equals("Razer Krait")) || (a2.equals("Razer Naga") && a1.equals("Razer Krait"))) {
                return 0.5;    
        } else if ((a1.equals("Razer Naga") && a2.equals("Razer Deathadder")) || (a2.equals("Razer Naga") && a1.equals("Razer Deathadder"))) {
                return 0.3;
        } else if ((a1.equals("Razer Abyssus") && a2.equals("Razer Krait")) || (a2.equals("Razer Abyssus") && a1.equals("Razer Krait"))) {
                return 0.6;
        } else if ((a1.equals("Razer Abyssus") && a2.equals("Razer Deathadder")) || (a2.equals("Razer Abyssus") && a1.equals("Razer Deathadder"))) {
                return 0.7;
        } else if ((a1.equals("Razer Deathadder") && a2.equals("Razer Krait")) || (a2.equals("Razer Deathadder") && a1.equals("Razer Krait"))) {
                return 0.8;
        } else {
                return 0;
        }
}   

public static double retornaSimFonte (String a1, String a2) {
        if (a1.equals("EVGA 1600W") && a2.equals("EVGA 1600W")) {
                return 1;
        } else if (a1.equals("Corsair 1500W") && a2.equals("Corsair 1500W")) {
                return 1;
        } else if (a1.equals("Coolermaster 1200W") && a2.equals("Coolermaster 1200W")) {
                return 1;
        } else if (a1.equals("Seasonic 1000W") && a2.equals("Seasonic 1000W")) {
                return 1;
        } else if ((a1.equals("EVGA 1600W") && a2.equals("Corsair 1500W")) || (a2.equals("EVGA 1500W") && a1.equals("Corsair 1500W"))) {
                return 0.8;
        } else if ((a1.equals("EVGA 1600W") && a2.equals("Coolermaster 1200W")) || (a2.equals("EVGA 1600W") && a1.equals("Coolermaster 1200W"))) {
                return 0.6;    
        } else if ((a1.equals("EVGA 1600W") && a2.equals("Seasonic 1000W")) || (a2.equals("EVGA 1600W") && a1.equals("Seasonic 1000W"))) {
                return 0.4;
        } else if ((a1.equals("Corsair 1500W") && a2.equals("Coolermaster 1200W")) || (a2.equals("Corsair 1500W") && a1.equals("Coolermaster 1200W"))) {
                return 0.7;
        } else if ((a1.equals("Corsair 1500W") && a2.equals("Seasonic 1000W")) || (a2.equals("Corsair 1500W") && a1.equals("Seasonic 1000W"))) {
                return 0.5;
        } else if ((a1.equals("Coolermaster 1200W") && a2.equals("Seasonic 1000W")) || (a2.equals("Coolermaster 1200W") && a1.equals("Seasonic 1000W"))) {
                return 0.8;
        } else {
                return 0;
        }
}

public static double retornaSimMonitor (String a1, String a2) {
        if (a1.equals("Benq 27p 144Hz") && a2.equals("Benq 27p 144Hz")) {
                return 1;
        } else if (a1.equals("Asus 27p 144Hz") && a2.equals("Asus 27p 144Hz")) {
                return 1;
        } else if (a1.equals("Asus 27p QuadHD") && a2.equals("Asus 27p QuadHD")) {
                return 1;
        } else if (a1.equals("LG 25p FullHD") && a2.equals("LG 25p FullHD")) {
                return 1;
        } else if ((a1.equals("Benq 27p 144Hz") && a2.equals("Asus 27p 144Hz")) || (a2.equals("Benq 27p 144Hz") && a1.equals("Asus 27p 144Hz"))) {
                return 0.8;
        } else if ((a1.equals("Benq 27p 144Hz") && a2.equals("Asus 27p QuadHD")) || (a2.equals("Benq 27p 144Hz") && a1.equals("Asus 27p QuadHD"))) {
                return 0.6;    
        } else if ((a1.equals("Benq 27p 144Hz") && a2.equals("LG 25p FullHD")) || (a2.equals("Benq 27p 144Hz") && a1.equals("LG 25p FullHD"))) {
                return 0.4;
        } else if ((a1.equals("Asus 27p 144Hz") && a2.equals("Asus 27p QuadHD")) || (a2.equals("Asus 27p 144Hz") && a1.equals("Asus 27p QuadHD"))) {
                return 0.7;
        } else if ((a1.equals("Asus 27p 144Hz") && a2.equals("LG 25p FullHD")) || (a2.equals("Asus 27p 144Hz") && a1.equals("LG 25p FullHD"))) {
                return 0.5;
        } else if ((a1.equals("Asus 27p QuadHD") && a2.equals("LG 25p FullHD")) || (a2.equals("Asus 27p QuadHD") && a1.equals("LG 25p FullHD"))) {
                return 0.8;
        } else {
                return 0;
        }
}

public static double retornaSimHeadset (String a1, String a2) {
        if (a1.equals("Razer Kraken") && a2.equals("Razer Kraken")) {
                return 1;
        } else if (a1.equals("Razer TiaMat") && a2.equals("Razer TiaMat")) {
                return 1;
        } else if (a1.equals("Razer Chiamera") && a2.equals("Razer Chiamera")) {
                return 1;
        } else if (a1.equals("Razer Manowar") && a2.equals("Razer Manowar")) {
                return 1;
        } else if ((a1.equals("Razer Kraken") && a2.equals("Razer TiaMat")) || (a2.equals("Razer Kraken") && a1.equals("Razer TiaMat"))) {
                return 0.7;
        } else if ((a1.equals("Razer Kraken") && a2.equals("Razer Chiamera")) || (a2.equals("Razer Kraken") && a1.equals("Razer Chiamera"))) {
                return 0.6;    
        } else if ((a1.equals("Razer Kraken") && a2.equals("Razer Manowar")) || (a2.equals("Razer Kraken") && a1.equals("Razer Manowar"))) {
                return 0.5;
        } else if ((a1.equals("Razer TiaMat") && a2.equals("Razer Chiamera")) || (a2.equals("Razer TiaMat") && a1.equals("Razer Chiamera"))) {
                return 0.7;
        } else if ((a1.equals("Razer TiaMat") && a2.equals("Razer Manowar")) || (a2.equals("Razer TiaMat") && a1.equals("Razer Manowar"))) {
                return 0.5;
        } else if ((a1.equals("Razer Chiamera") && a2.equals("Razer Manowar")) || (a2.equals("Razer Chiamera") && a1.equals("Razer Manowar"))) {
                return 0.8;
        } else {
                return 0;
        }
}

public static double retornaSimMotherboard (String a1, String a2) {
        if (a1.equals("ATX Maximus VIII") && a2.equals("ATX Maximus VIII")) {
                return 1;
        } else if (a1.equals("ATX ROG STRIX") && a2.equals("ATX ROG STRIX")) {
                return 1;
        } else if (a1.equals("ATX Sabertooth") && a2.equals("ATX Sabertooth")) {
                return 1;
        } else if (a1.equals("ATX 970 PRO") && a2.equals("ATX 970 PRO")) {
                return 1;
        } else if ((a1.equals("ATX Maximus VIII") && a2.equals("ATX ROG STRIX")) || (a2.equals("ATX Maximus VIII") && a1.equals("ATX ROG STRIX"))) {
                return 0.8;
        } else if ((a1.equals("ATX Maximus VIII") && a2.equals("ATX Sabertooth")) || (a2.equals("ATX Maximus VIII") && a1.equals("ATX Sabertooth"))) {
                return 0.6;    
        } else if ((a1.equals("ATX Maximus VIII") && a2.equals("ATX 970 PRO")) || (a2.equals("ATX Maximus VIII") && a1.equals("ATX 970 PRO"))) {
                return 0.5;
        } else if ((a1.equals("ATX ROG STRIX") && a2.equals("ATX Sabertooth")) || (a2.equals("ATX ROG STRIX") && a1.equals("ATX Sabertooth"))) {
                return 0.7;
        } else if ((a1.equals("ATX ROG STRIX") && a2.equals("ATX 970 PRO")) || (a2.equals("ATX ROG STRIX") && a1.equals("ATX 970 PRO"))) {
                return 0.6;
        } else if ((a1.equals("ATX Sabertooth") && a2.equals("ATX 970 PRO")) || (a2.equals("ATX Sabertooth") && a1.equals("ATX 970 PRO"))) {
                return 0.9;
        } else {
                return 0;
        }
}
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<String> gabinete = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> processador = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> memoria = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> hd = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> ssd = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> gpu = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> teclado = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> mouse = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> fonte = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> refrigeracao = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> monitor = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> headset = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> motherboard = new ArrayList<String>();

         gabinete.add("Mid Tower");
        gabinete.add("Full Tower");
        processador.add("i7 6700K");
        processador.add("i7 6700");
        processador.add("i5 6600K");
        processador.add("i5 6600");
        memoria.add("HyperX 8GB 1600");
        memoria.add("Vengeance 8GB 1600");
        memoria.add("HyperX 8GB 1866");
        memoria.add("HyperX 8GB 2133");
        hd.add("WD 1TB 7200");
        hd.add("Seagate 1TB 7200");
        hd.add("Seagate 2TB 7200");
        ssd.add("Kingston 120GB");
        ssd.add("Sandisk 120GB");
        ssd.add("Kingston 240GB");
        ssd.add("Sandisk 240GB");
        gpu.add("AMD R9 390");
        gpu.add("AMD R9 Fury");
        gpu.add("AMD R9 390X");
        gpu.add("GTX 980 TI");
        teclado.add("Razer BlackWidow");
        teclado.add("Razer DeathStalker");
        teclado.add("Razer Cynosa");
        mouse.add("Razer Naga");
        mouse.add("Razer Abyssus");
        mouse.add("Razer Krait");
        mouse.add("Razer Deathadder");
        fonte.add("EVGA 1600W");
        fonte.add("Corsair 1500W");
        fonte.add("Coolermaster 1200W");
        fonte.add("SeaSonic 1000W");
        refrigeracao.add("Água");
        refrigeracao.add("Ar");
        monitor.add("Benq 27p 144Hz");
        monitor.add("Asus 27p 144Hz");
        monitor.add("Asus 27p QuadHD");
        monitor.add("LG 25p FullHD");
        headset.add("Razer Kraken");
        headset.add("Razer TiaMat");
        headset.add("Razer Chiamera");
        headset.add("Razer Manowar");
        motherboard.add("ATX Maximus VIII");
        motherboard.add("ATX ROG STRIX");
        motherboard.add("ATX Sabertooth");
        motherboard.add("ATX 970 PRO");

         String gabinetesel;
        String processadorsel;
        String memoriasel;
        String hdsel;
        String ssdsel;
        String gpusel;
        String tecladosel;
        String mousesel;
        String fontesel;
        String refrigeracaosel;
        String monitorsel;
        String headsetsel;
        String motherboardsel;
        // VARIAVEIS PARA RECEBER O PESO DE CADA VARIAVEL DO RBC
        Double pesogabinete;
        Double pesoprocessador;
        Double pesomemoria;
        Double pesohd;
        Double pesossd;
        Double pesogpu;
        Double pesoteclado;
        Double pesomouse;
        Double pesofonte;
        Double pesorefrigeracao;
        Double pesomonitor;
        Double pesoheadset;
        Double pesomotherboard;
        // PEGA O VALOR SELECIONADO DA LISTA E COLOCA NA VARIAVEL CRIADA PARA ISSO
        gabinetesel = "Mid Tower";
        processadorsel = "i7 6700K";
        memoriasel = "HyperX 8GB 1600";
        hdsel = "WD 1TB 7200";
        ssdsel = "Kingston 120GB";
        gpusel = "AMD R9 390";
        tecladosel = "Razer BlackWidow";
        mousesel = "Razer Naga";
        fontesel = "EVGA 1600W";
        refrigeracaosel = "Água";
        monitorsel = "Benq 27p 144Hz";
        headsetsel = "Razer Kraken";
        motherboardsel = "ATX Maximus VIII";
        // PEGA OS VALORES DE PESO DE CADA VARIAVEL     
        pesogabinete = 1.0;
        pesoprocessador = 1.0;
        pesomemoria = 1.0;
        pesohd = 1.0;
        pesossd = 1.0;
        pesogpu = 1.0;
        pesoteclado = 1.0;
        pesomouse = 1.0;
        pesofonte = 1.0;
        pesorefrigeracao = 1.0;
        pesomonitor = 1.0;
        pesoheadset = 1.0;
        pesomotherboard = 1.0;

        Vector row = new Vector();
        //cria tabela
        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();

        double prob;
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i ++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++){
                for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++){
                    for (int l = 0; l < 3; l++){
                        for (int m = 0; m < 4; m++){
                            for (int n = 0; n < 4; n++){
                                for (int o = 0; o < 3; o++){
                                    for (int p = 0; p < 4; p++){
                                        for (int q = 0; q < 4; q++) {
                                            for (int r = 0; r < 2; r++){
                                                for (int s = 0; s < 4; s++){
                                                    for (int t = 0; t < 4; t++){
                                                        for (int u = 0; u < 4; u++) {
                                                             prob = ((pesogabinete * retornaSimGabinete(gabinetesel,gabinete.get(i))) + (pesoprocessador *(retornaSimProc(processadorsel,processador.get(j)))) + (pesomemoria * (retornaSimMem(memoriasel,memoria.get(k)))) + (pesohd * (retornaSimHd(hdsel,hd.get(l)))) + (pesossd * (retornaSimSsd(ssdsel,ssd.get(m)))) + (pesogpu * (retornaSimGpu(gpusel,gpu.get(n)))) +  (pesoteclado * (retornaSimTeclado(tecladosel,teclado.get(o)))) + (pesomouse * (retornaSimMouse(mousesel,mouse.get(p)))) + (pesofonte * (retornaSimFonte(fontesel,fonte.get(q)))) + (pesorefrigeracao * (retornaSimRefrigeracao(refrigeracaosel,refrigeracao.get(r)))) + (pesomonitor * (retornaSimMonitor(monitorsel,monitor.get(s)))) + (pesoheadset * (retornaSimHeadset(headsetsel,headset.get(t)))) + (pesomotherboard * (retornaSimMotherboard(motherboardsel,motherboard.get(u))))) / (pesogabinete+pesoprocessador+pesomemoria+pesohd+pesossd+pesomouse+pesoteclado+pesogpu+pesofonte+pesorefrigeracao+pesomonitor+pesoheadset+pesomotherboard);
                                                             System.out.println(gabinete.get(i) + "," + processador.get(j) + "," + memoria.get(k) + "," + hd.get(l) + "," + ssd.get(m) + "," + gpu.get(n) + "," + teclado.get(o) + "," + mouse.get(p) + "," + fonte.get(q) + "," + refrigeracao.get(r) + "," + monitor.get(s) + "," + headset.get(t) + "," + motherboard.get(u) + " --> " + (prob*100) + "%" );
 row.add(gabinete.get(i));
                                                             row.add(processador.get(j));
                                                             row.add(memoria.get(k));
                                                             row.add(hd.get(l));
                                                             row.add(ssd.get(m));
                                                             row.add(gpu.get(n));
                                                             row.add(teclado.get(o));
                                                             row.add(mouse.get(p));
                                                             row.add(fonte.get(q));
                                                             row.add(refrigeracao.get(r));
                                                             row.add(monitor.get(s));
                                                             row.add(headset.get(t));
                                                             row.add(motherboard.get(u));
                                                             row.add(Double.toString(prob));
                                                             model.addRow (row);

                                                        }                                  
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }         


















    }
```

Comment: Por favor adicione um [mcve] para que seja possivel reproduzir o código.

Comment: Ou simplesmente utilize `table.getRowSorter().toggleSortOrder(modelColumnIndex)`

Comment: Amigo, o código completo possui mais de 50000 linhas e aqui só é permitido postar 30000, teria como você mostrar esse método que você falou naquele meu exemplo acima? Grato.

Comment: Sobre o [mcve], leitura recomendada: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/5368/28595

Comment: Atualizei o post, acredito que agora seja possível reproduzir o problema.

Comment: Não consegui reproduzir o código, inumeros componentes estão em falta.

Comment: @diegofm editei novamente o post, retirei todos os componente do jFrame e já deixei uma entrada de dados pronta, agora é possível executar o código apenas colando ele, não precisa fazer nenhuma alteração, minha dúvida agora é o seguinte, como exibo os dados da variável `prob` em um tabela com 14 colunas (13 dos atributos [gabinete, processador, memoria,..] e 1 da similaridade [variável prob]) ordenada de forma crescente pela variável prob.

Comment: Onde está a jtable? O código é executável mas no problema você fala de ordenar jtable por determinada coluna, e no código não tem uma. Mal pergunte isso vem de um banco de dados? Não é mais facil trazer já ordenado de la, já que são muitos dados? Fazer isso na gui você vai travar sua aplicação a cada item que adicionar.

Comment: Não estou trazendo de um banco de dados, estou fazendo direto pela GUI mesmo, eu tirei meu código da jtable pois nao estava funcionando, vou atualizar ele ali.

Comment: Atualizado, o problema que acontece agora é que ele da erro na hora de adicionar a tabela quando eu uso o metodo `row.clear()` , se eu tirar o método `row.clear()` ele funciona parcialmente, o único problema é que ele coloca todas as linhas iguais (fica sempre o primeiro atributo, pois ele não limpa o vetor). Sabe como posso arrumar isso daquele jeito que falei ?

Comment: Ai já é um problema completamente diferente do da pergunta. Você pode ordenar no `TableModel ` ou diretamente na tabela com o comando que eu mostrei, mas com esse código não tem como nem demonstrar no seu programa. Posso demonstrar com um exemplo diferente e você tentar adaptar pro seu codigo.

Comment: Poderia mostrar o exemplo? Achei estranho ele dar erro no `row.clear()` ...

Comment: A resposta abaixo lhe atendeu?

Answer (score 1):

Para reordenar de acordo com os dados de uma determinada coluna, você precisa primeiro implementar o método [**`getColumnClass`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html#getColumnClass(int)) do seu `TableModel`, para que seja conhecido o tipo de dado da coluna que você quer ordenar e assim seja possível reordená-la.

Também é necessário definir um [`RowSorter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/RowSorter.html) para sua tabela, pois é esta classe que permite definir um filtro e ordenação numa `JTable`. Uma vez aplicado a *JTable* através do [**`setRowSorter`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#setRowSorter(javax.swing.RowSorter)), basta chamar [**`toggleSortOrder`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/RowSorter.html#toggleSortOrder(int)) passando a coluna como parâmetro.

Veja um exemplo de uso do `RowSorter` e do `toggleSortOrder`:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class RowSorterDemo {

    public void createAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Sort Table Demo");

        Object rows[][] = {
            {"J", 23},
            {"R", 24,},
            {"E", 21,},
            {"B", 27,},
            {"A", 25,},
            {"S", 22,}};

        String columns[] = {"Name", "Age"};

        TableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(rows, columns) {
            @Override
            public Class getColumnClass(int column) {
                switch (column) {
                    case 0:
                        return String.class;
                    case 1:
                        return Integer.class;
                    default:
                        return Object.class;
                }
            }
        };

        JTable table = new JTable(model);
        //é o RowSorter que ordenará sua tabela
        RowSorter<TableModel> sorter = new TableRowSorter<>(model);
        //aplica o sorter a tabela
        table.setRowSorter(sorter);

        JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(table);

        JButton button = new JButton("OrdenarPorIdade");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                //passa o rowsorter e a coluna da tabela
                //neste caso é a segunda
                reorderingTableByColumn(sorter, 1);
            }
        });

        frame.add(pane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 200));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void reorderingTableByColumn(RowSorter sorter, int column) {
        //reordena a tabela pela coluna Age
        sorter.toggleSortOrder(column);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new RowSorterDemo().createAndShowGUI());
    }
}
```

O resultado do exemplo é:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No exemplo, eu criei um método a parte que reordena a tabela pela segunda coluna ao clicar em um botão, mas você pode deixar a chamada direto na inicialização do programa.

> Obs.: vale mencionar que, pelo número de dados que você tem nessa tabela, esta solução poderá ocasionar pequenos travamentos na aplicação toda vez que for reorganizar a tabela.

---

**Referências:**

[Using RowSorter to sort a JTable](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/UsingRowSortertosortaJTable.htm)

[Sorting and Filtering(documentação)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting)

[Ordenando e Filtrando Tabelas](http://www.devmedia.com.br/ordenando-e-filtrando-tabelas-com-o-java-se-6-0/1668)

[Table Sorting and Filtering](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=661371&seqNum=4)